# go test: only run tests that contain a build tag?

Tags: go, testing

I have a set of long running tests, defined with the build tag. For example,

```
// file some_test.go
//+build func_test

(rest of file with test cases)
```

And I have many other shorter running tests, without this build flag.
Is there a way I can easily run only the tests containing the build tag "func_test"?

Note that if I just run `go test -tags func_test`, it runs ALL tests including the ones in `some_test.go`.

Comment: Obviously adding more tests doesn’t prevent the existing tests from running You either need to exclude the other tests by name, or by constraints, the choice is yours.

Answer (score 11):

As per the golang Doc https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

The build tag lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the package. So if you want to run the test only for the build tags func_test then you need to provide a different tag for the other tests.

Here is an example:
I have following 2 test files in my test directory.

func_test.go

```
//+build test_all func_test

package go_build_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestNormal(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("testing:", t.Name())

}
```

other_test.go

```
//+build test_all,!func_test

package go_build_test

import "testing"
import "fmt"

func TestOtherCase(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("testing:", t.Name())
}
```

Now If you want to run all the tests.

```
$ go test -tags=test_all
testing: TestNormal
testing: TestOtherCase
PASS
ok      _/D_/Project/ARC/source/prototype/go/src/go-build-test  0.186s
```

Only running the func_test

```
$ go test -tags=func_test
testing: TestNormal
PASS
ok      _/D_/Project/ARC/source/prototype/go/src/go-build-test  1.395s
```

The trick is to work with the //+build comment with AND/OR conditions.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was afraid of. This means that all of our developers who write unittests need to be aware of this new tag called "test_all"

Answer (score 6):

You could name your test by convention.
I.e let your long running test function start with `TestLong_`
Then run them with
`go test ./... -run TestLong -tags func_test`

Answer (score -4):

You need the `=` sign after `-tags`

`go test -tags=func_test`

Comment: No, that's not necessary